# Instant transition in MotionLayout instead of animation

Tags: android, android-animation

In my app I have TextView and RecyclerView. On RV scrolling font size of TV should decrease. Respectively, I expect the size of TV itself to decrease as well.

The problem is that when I set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for TextView in Constraints in both start and end points no animation occurs. Just the instant transition between two points ([video](https://youtube.com/shorts/kd8DbE2-wKA?feature=share)).

The fact that I can't understand is why when I set `android:layout_height` of my TextView to some specific value in dp's, smooth animation occurs ([video](https://youtube.com/shorts/rHtwLq4drKQ?feature=share)). But I want to make TextView height wrap_content so it could be connected to textSize.

What is the reason of this case? How can I make animation smooth and make TextView height wrap_content at the same time?

My motion XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <OnSwipe motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/rv" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textSize"
                motion:customDimension="18sp" />
        </Constraint>


        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textSize"
                motion:customDimension="12sp" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showPaths="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:text="My friends"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </TextView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```